# Wheeler-deWitt equation as a renormalization group flow

Tags: general-relativity, string-theory, resource-recommendations, renormalization, quantum-gravity

I recently heard a comment that Wheeler-deWitt equation can be interpreted as RG flow equations. However, I haven't been able to find appropriate references for the same. Could someone suggest any papers where this might be discussed?